# SpecRun runs no tests when running tests via CLI

Tags: c#, specflow, specrun

I've been setting up a simple browser automation framework in specflow and everything works when I run the tests from VS. But if i try to run them through specrun via the commandline; it runs but no tests are listed. Am I missing something here, because I feel that I've followed the documentation.

This is what I run:

```
> specrun.exe run Browser_Automation_Framework\Default.srprofile
```

And this is the result i get

```
************************
*** SpecFlow+ Runner ***
************************

Version 3.9.7+4ac605a907
Assembly Version 3.9.0.0
Released 03-03-2015

Copyright © SpecFlow Team
http://www.specflow.org/plus

Checking activation
Activated.
Activation check completed

SpecRun Console Tracer - press CTRL+C to stop before starting the next test

Discovered 0 tests
Thread#0:


Done.
Result: tests executed with warnings
  Total: 0
  Succeeded: 0
  Ignored: 0
  Pending: 0
  Skipped: 0
  Failed: 0
```

My Default.srprofile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Settings 
      projectName="Browser Automation Framework" 
      reportTemplate="ReportTemplate.cshtml"/>
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="1" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
  <TestAssemblyPaths>
    <TestAssemblyPath>Browser_Automation_Framework.dll</TestAssemblyPath>
  </TestAssemblyPaths>
    <DeploymentTransformation>
        <Steps>
            <EnvironmentVariable variable="BaseURL" value="https://google.dk/" />
        </Steps>
    </DeploymentTransformation>
</TestProfile>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a bit late but please ensure that the dll's path is the correct, generally when you don't specify a valid path for the dll, specrun runs but wihtout catch the tests

Try to put all the dll's path in the  tag

```
<TestAssemblyPath>C:\Users\user\Documents\Repository\baseFolder/bin/debug/projectName.dll<\TestAssemblyPath>
```